# Color bar use in matlab surface image

Tags: image, matlab, colorbar

Im displaying a 3D matrix, as an image using the surf tool in a 2D display as follows:

```
figure;
title('Plot')
surf(Matrix,'EdgeColor','None');
view(2);
colorbar;
```

There are areas of the image that i am interested in distinguishing from other areas, however since there are a few very high/ very low background values, the image doesn't make the colour of the interesting areas distinct, since the colour bar has to take into account the whole spread of the values.

Is there a way to change the colour bar so it takes the average values more into account as apposed the extreme values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`caxis`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/caxis.html) option to tune your color limits, and [`prctile`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html?refresh=true) to get the percentile level. Combining them will let you highlight portions of you data.

e.g.

```
caxis(prctile(Matrix(:),[5 90]))
```

will limit the colormap to the data above the %5 and below %90. Modify this values at will

Comment: In the code above, where would that go, i've tried at the end but it doesn't change it, and if I put it after the surf bit it just returns a 3D plot

Comment: @benwhelan94 sorry what? the surf bit SHOULD return a 3D plot, that is a surf!!!! you set up view(2) and that gives you a look of the 3D plot from the top, but it is still a 3D plot!

Comment: @benwhelan94 anyway, putting it in the end works on my machine

Comment: Is caxis the right one then? I still get an error with it, saying that there are not enough input arguments. In the code above how would i input the caxis bit for it to work?

Comment: @benwhelan94 there was a typo, I corrected it. However, you didn't mention that there was an error earlier, and the fix is obvious. please, check the answer/documentation before asking and be complete when reporting problems

Comment: The matrix is a 64x64 array, so i'm not really sure why I'm getting the 'not enough input arguments' error?

Comment: @benwhelan94 THERE WAS A TYPO. I corrected it. Copy paste the new line and use it.

Comment: Apologies! I thought you meant the change from the two functions. Thank you, it works fine now!

Comment: @benwhelan94 consider accepting the answer as valid then ;)